# Why isn't pipe() working after forking twice between parallel child processes?

Tags: c, string, unix, pipe, fork

My goal is to send a string from one child process to another. I set up a pipe in the parent process, then fork twice. Both reached statements print, why does the piped message not?

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<string.h>
int main (char * argv[], int argc)
{
int arr[2];
pipe(arr);

int id = 0;
int pid = fork();
id = 1;
if(pid > 0) pid = fork();

if(pid > 0)
{
    close(arr[0]);
    close(arr[1]);
    wait(NULL);
}
else if (id == 0)
{
    close(arr[0]);
    char message[] = "HYPERTEXT TRANSFER\n";
    write(arr[1],message,strlen(message)+1);
    printf("reached\n");
}
else if(id == 1)
{
    printf("reached\n");
    close(arr[1]);
    char * buf = malloc (sizeof(char)* 20);
    read(arr[0], buf, 20);
    printf("%s", buf);


}
return 0;
}
```

The program outputs "reached" twice.

Comment: id is 1 for all processes. You are not going into the `else if (id == 0)` to write anything.

Comment: `id = 1` should be inside `if (pid > 0)` so it won't be true in the first child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id is 1 for all processes. You are not going into the else if (id == 0) to write anything, Hence, you are attempting to read from an empty pipe.

Comment: Are you sure that is the case? I should clarify the program outputs "reached" twice.

Comment: You were correct, I will accept this answer when the cool down time is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that for both your child processes, `id = 1`. Indeed, both child processes execute the line `id = 1` so they are both receivers.

Try:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<string.h>
int main (char * argv[], int argc)
{
int arr[2];
pipe(arr);

int id = 0;
int pid = fork();

if(pid > 0) {
    pid = fork();
    id = 1; // Here only the second child process (and the parent process, but who cares) have id == 1.
}

if(pid > 0)
{
    close(arr[0]);
    close(arr[1]);
    wait(NULL);
}
else if (id == 0)
{
    close(arr[0]);
    char message[] = "HYPERTEXT TRANSFER\n";
    write(arr[1],message,strlen(message)+1);
    printf("reached\n");
}
else if(id == 1)
{
    printf("reached\n");
    close(arr[1]);
    char * buf = malloc (sizeof(char)* 20);
    read(arr[0], buf, 20);
    printf("%s", buf);


}
return 0;
}
```